# vuejs 2 to vuejs 3, how to insert component in contenteditable?

Tags: vue.js, contenteditable, vuejs3

With vuejs 2, I can insert a component (called testo2 for my test) inside a div contenteditable, the code :

```js
addtesto(){
  let ComponentClass = Vue.extend(testo2);
  let instance = new ComponentClass();
  instance.$mount();

  let sel, range;
  if (window.getSelection) {
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
      range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
      range.deleteContents();
      range.insertNode(instance.$el);
      window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    }
  }
}
```

I try since a long time, to convert this code for vuejs 3 and his composition api (inside a setup() ), but this code doesn't work :

```js
const addtesto = () => {
// here it changes
  const instance = createApp(testo2);
  instance.mount();

  // here it is same thing
  let sel, range;
  if (window.getSelection) {
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
      range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
      range.deleteContents();
      range.insertNode(instance.$el);
      window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    }}};
```

It's a problem with $el in "range.insertNode(instance.$el);" but I think the component testo2 never is mounted.

someone knows how to do ?

Answer (score 0):

`instance.mount();` requires an element to be passed

not sure exactly what's going on here, but you could try something like this

```js
const addtesto = () => {
  const instance = createApp(testo2);
  let sel, range;
  if (window.getSelection) {
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
      range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
      instance.mount(range); // mount to range
      window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    }
  }
};
```

I assume `range` is an element, and you can either mount directly to it, or create a child and mount to that child.

Comment: In fact, the new component must be mounted and after, range insert a node from this component (the new component must be sent to range). you are right for mount(), I must to find how to do in vuejs 3, the methods "Vue.extend(newComponent)".

Comment: are you trying to make the component the element?

Comment: yes Daniel. I want to be able to insert a component to allow the user to use methods and other useful things that Vue components bring.
After validation, the text should not be changed.. On Vuejs 2, it works good, but I am curious and I wanted to test vuejs 3 ( it is awesome).

Comment: how does this fit within the `setup()` function or is it not using composition API? Can you post more code?